# Sybase ASE stored procedure creation date

Tags: database, stored-procedures, sybase, sybase-ase15

Is there any way of finding what is the creation date of a stored procedure in Sybase ASE 15? The actual version is 15.0.3.

I know i can find information on this in the `sysobjects` table, but due to the fact that stored procedures are dropped and re-created anytime they are modified, this shows the last time somebody modified the stored procedure.

Is there any way of finding when was a stored procedure first created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless you have auditing enabled. When you drop a proc, it's removed from the catalogs. When you recreate it, it's added again with a new object ID and new creation date.